# jQuery: Check if an object has class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to check if an object has a class. Seems simple enough, but I can't get it to work. Here is my code:

**Javascript**

```
$('ul.nav li').click(function(){    
    if $(this).hasClass('selected') {
        alert('This is selected!');
    }

    else {
        alert('This is not selected!');
    }
});

$('ul.nav li:first-child').addClass('selected');
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>Who we work for</li>
    <li>Articles and interviews</li>
    <li>Job openings</li>
    <li>What the #%!$@ is Post Typography?</li>
</ul>

<ul class="content">
    <li>This is who we work for.</li>
    <li>These are articles and interviews.</li>
    <li>These are our job openings.</li>
    <li>This is some info about Post Typography.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you need the parentheses around the `if` condition?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
if $(this).hasClass('selected') {
```

should be

```
if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
```

This would have been easily observed when you have had a look into the browser's error console. :-)

Answer (score 0):

include the full code in

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('ul.nav li').click(function(){    
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        alert('This is selected!');
    }

    else {
        alert('This is not selected!');
    }
});

$('ul.nav li:first-child').addClass('selected');

});
```

hope this helps..